# I want to copy a couple different files in different folders

Tags: python, bash

eg.
I have sam1_1.gz sam2_1.gz sam3_1.gz ..200 of these and I have corresponding folder sam1, sam2 sam3. I would like to copy sam1.gz to /home/users/sam1, sam2.gz to /home/users/sam2 and so on. I would like to include paths for them as well

Comment: `for i in {1..200};do cp "sam${i}.gz" "sam${i}"; done`

Comment: Welcome to SO! I think you could improve your chances of getting an answer if you review the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and modify your question.

Comment: My filename is sam1_1.gz and when I do       (as a test I am trying 5)                                                    for i in {1_1..5_1};do cp "sam${i}.fastq.gz"  "sam${i}"; done
cp: cannot stat ‘sam{1_1..5_1}.fastq.gz’: No such file or directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create files:

```
for i in {1..200}; do touch $i.gz; done
```

Then run:

```
#!/bin/bash

for filename in *.gz; do
  file="${filename%.*}"
  mkdir $file
  mv $filename ./$file
done
```

This extracts the filename without the extension - makes the directory and moves the file.

edit:
As per your comment I don't know what you're doing wrong:

```
[vagrant@Tools-18 zips]$ touch sam1_1.gz
[vagrant@Tools-18 zips]$ touch sam1_2.gz
[vagrant@Tools-18 zips]$ touch sam2_2.gz
[vagrant@Tools-18 zips]$ touch sam2_1.gz
[vagrant@Tools-18 zips]$ bash 1.sh
[vagrant@Tools-18 zips]$ ls -lrth
total 4.0K
-rw-rw-r--. 1 vagrant vagrant 104 Feb  7 16:05 1.sh
drwxrwxr-x. 2 vagrant vagrant  23 Feb  7 16:30 sam1_1
drwxrwxr-x. 2 vagrant vagrant  23 Feb  7 16:30 sam1_2
drwxrwxr-x. 2 vagrant vagrant  23 Feb  7 16:30 sam2_1
drwxrwxr-x. 2 vagrant vagrant  23 Feb  7 16:30 sam2_2
[vagrant@Tools-18 zips]$ ls ./sam2_2/
sam2_2.gz
```

final edit2:

```
[vagrant@Tools-18 script]$ cat 1.sh
#!/bin/bash

zipdir=/home/vagrant/zips
move_to_dir=/home/vagrant/new_directory
cd $zipdir
for filename in *.gz; do
  file="${filename%.*}"
  echo "making directory: $move_to_dir/$file"
  mkdir -p $move_to_dir/$file
  echo "moving $filename to $move_to_dir/$file/"
  mv $filename $move_to_dir/$file/
done
[vagrant@Tools-18 script]$ ls /home/vagrant/zips
sam100_1.gz  sam115_1.gz  sam130_1.gz  sam145_1.gz  sam161_1.gz  sam176_1.gz  sam19_1.gz   sam26_1.gz  sam4_1.gz   sam57_1.gz  sam72_1.gz  sam88_1.gz
sam101_1.gz  sam116_1.gz  sam131_1.gz  sam146_1.gz  sam16_1.gz   sam177_1.gz  sam192_1.gz  sam27_1.gz  sam42_1.gz  sam58_1.gz  sam73_1.gz  sam89_1.gz
sam10_1.gz   sam117_1.gz  sam13_1.gz   sam147_1.gz  sam162_1.gz  sam178_1.gz  sam193_1.gz  sam28_1.gz  sam43_1.gz  sam59_1.gz  sam74_1.gz  sam90_1.gz
sam102_1.gz  sam118_1.gz  sam132_1.gz  sam148_1.gz  sam163_1.gz  sam179_1.gz  sam194_1.gz  sam29_1.gz  sam44_1.gz  sam60_1.gz  sam75_1.gz  sam91_1.gz
sam103_1.gz  sam119_1.gz  sam133_1.gz  sam149_1.gz  sam164_1.gz  sam180_1.gz  sam195_1.gz  sam30_1.gz  sam45_1.gz  sam61_1.gz  sam76_1.gz  sam9_1.gz
sam104_1.gz  sam1_1.gz    sam134_1.gz  sam150_1.gz  sam165_1.gz  sam181_1.gz  sam196_1.gz  sam31_1.gz  sam46_1.gz  sam6_1.gz   sam77_1.gz  sam92_1.gz
sam105_1.gz  sam120_1.gz  sam135_1.gz  sam151_1.gz  sam166_1.gz  sam18_1.gz   sam197_1.gz  sam3_1.gz   sam47_1.gz  sam62_1.gz  sam78_1.gz  sam93_1.gz
sam106_1.gz  sam121_1.gz  sam136_1.gz  sam15_1.gz   sam167_1.gz  sam182_1.gz  sam198_1.gz  sam32_1.gz  sam48_1.gz  sam63_1.gz  sam79_1.gz  sam94_1.gz
sam107_1.gz  sam12_1.gz   sam137_1.gz  sam152_1.gz  sam168_1.gz  sam183_1.gz  sam199_1.gz  sam33_1.gz  sam49_1.gz  sam64_1.gz  sam80_1.gz  sam95_1.gz
sam108_1.gz  sam122_1.gz  sam138_1.gz  sam153_1.gz  sam169_1.gz  sam184_1.gz  sam200_1.gz  sam34_1.gz  sam50_1.gz  sam65_1.gz  sam81_1.gz  sam96_1.gz
sam109_1.gz  sam123_1.gz  sam139_1.gz  sam154_1.gz  sam170_1.gz  sam185_1.gz  sam20_1.gz   sam35_1.gz  sam51_1.gz  sam66_1.gz  sam8_1.gz   sam97_1.gz
sam110_1.gz  sam124_1.gz  sam140_1.gz  sam155_1.gz  sam171_1.gz  sam186_1.gz  sam21_1.gz   sam36_1.gz  sam5_1.gz   sam67_1.gz  sam82_1.gz  sam98_1.gz
sam111_1.gz  sam125_1.gz  sam141_1.gz  sam156_1.gz  sam17_1.gz   sam187_1.gz  sam2_1.gz    sam37_1.gz  sam52_1.gz  sam68_1.gz  sam83_1.gz  sam99_1.gz
sam11_1.gz   sam126_1.gz  sam14_1.gz   sam157_1.gz  sam172_1.gz  sam188_1.gz  sam22_1.gz   sam38_1.gz  sam53_1.gz  sam69_1.gz  sam84_1.gz
sam112_1.gz  sam127_1.gz  sam142_1.gz  sam158_1.gz  sam173_1.gz  sam189_1.gz  sam23_1.gz   sam39_1.gz  sam54_1.gz  sam70_1.gz  sam85_1.gz
sam113_1.gz  sam128_1.gz  sam143_1.gz  sam159_1.gz  sam174_1.gz  sam190_1.gz  sam24_1.gz   sam40_1.gz  sam55_1.gz  sam71_1.gz  sam86_1.gz
sam114_1.gz  sam129_1.gz  sam144_1.gz  sam160_1.gz  sam175_1.gz  sam191_1.gz  sam25_1.gz   sam41_1.gz  sam56_1.gz  sam7_1.gz   sam87_1.gz
[vagrant@Tools-18 script]$ ls /home/vagrant/new_directory
lsmaking directory: /home/vagrant/new_directory/sam99_1
moving sam99_1.gz to /home/vagrant/new_directory/sam99_1/
[vagrant@Tools-18 script]$ ls /home/vagrant/new_directory/sam99_1/
sam99_1.gz
[vagrant@Tools-18 script]$
: cannot access /home/vagrant/new_directory: No such file or directory
[vagrant@Tools-18 script]$ bash 1.sh
making directory: /home/vagrant/new_directory/sam100_1
moving sam100_1.gz to /home/vagrant/new_directory/sam100_1/
...
making directory: /home/vagrant/new_directory/sam99_1
moving sam99_1.gz to /home/vagrant/new_directory/sam99_1/
[vagrant@Tools-18 script]$ ls /home/vagrant/new_directory/sam99_1/
sam99_1.gz
```

Comment: My filename is sam1_1.gz sam2_1.gz and so on . It is giving me an error

Comment: @user12859525 - See my edit - it works with underscores too. I don't know what else you're doing wrong.

Comment: for i in {1_1..5_1}; do touch $i.gz; done
touch: cannot touch ‘{1_1..1_1}.gz’: Permission denied

Comment: I am running it on the cluster and that could be an issue. I have the files in one folder there and I want to copy them to their corresponding named folders in another folder

Comment: The touch was simply to create the files you don't need to do that. You just need to run the script (I have it saved as 1.sh). You will need to put relative paths in. I have simply used the current directory, however you can prefix it with what you want

Comment: See my final edit. I've added some extra features for you (mainly the zipdir and the target dir). I'm all for helping people, but there's literally no further I can take this. I have given you a working script and demonstrated it is working in multiple ways.

Answer (score 0):

```
import shutil
root, folders, files = next(os.walk('.'))
for file in files:
    if file.endswith('.gz'):
        src=os.path.join(root, file)
        dst=os.path.join(root, file[:-3], file)
        try:
            shutil.copy(
                src=src,
                dst=dst
            )
        except FileNotFoundError:
            print(f"Could not copy {src} to {dst}: folder {os.path.join(root, file[:-3])} missing.")
```